# Decimals in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I need to display 45.556 as 45.55 what is the format i need to use in true dbgrid pro 7.0.

Comment: What exactly is your rounding algorithm? Always round down? Always round towards zero? Truncate at 2 decimal places? Remove the 'last' significant figure? Always display the value 45.55? ;-)

Comment: For inspiration, see: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652
"How To Implement Custom Rounding Procedures"

Comment: Correction: Format rounds away from zero, not bankers at all!

Answer (score 9):

Sorry not familiar with dbgird pro 7.0.  If you are looking not looking to trucate the 6 as you showed in your example (rounded 45.556 is 45.56) you can use the format command, which will format your number to two decimal places, rounding accordingly.

```
format(*value*, "0.00")
```

Using "0.00" formats the number to default to zero in the position the zero is in.
Using "#.##" formats the number to default to space (nothing)

If you don't want to round the number and are only looking to get the number plus the right two decimal places.

```
Left(cStr(value), instr(cStr(value), ".") + 2))
```

Retrieves from the left your number plus 2 past the decimal, truncating the rest.  You may not need to cStr(), as VB may explicitly convert it first.
using cStr() may create a space before the number which is from a minus sign would go, format() doesn't do this, if you see this issue in your grid.

Comment: Small comment: use `"0.##"` if you want to not display trailing zeroes. `0` before `.` is needed, because if you have numer `0.010` you will got `,01`. Changing `#.` to `0.` will fix this

Answer (score 1):

To handle this through the grids properties, set the column's NumberFormat = Fixed, unless it is a currency value, then you should use Currency.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally without resulting to string manipulation that will blow up in European countries (which use a , instead of a . for the decimal place)...  However, if any combination of floatval and decimalPlaces > 9 you are going to have overflow issues...

```
Public Function Floor(ByVal floatval As Double, optional decimalPlaces as Long = 0) As Long
    Dim intval As Long
    intval = Round(floatval)
    If intval > floatval Then 
         intval = intval - 1
    End If

    if decimalPlaces > 0 then
        floatval = float / (10 ^ decimalPlaces)
    end if

    Floor = intval
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it in two different ways with different results. We will take the first two digits after the dot symbol "." to get the result:
   45.55 out of 45.556

```
Dim a As Double  'This must be DOUBLE not long
a = 45.556

MsgBox Left(a, InStr(a, ".") + 2) 'Result: 45.55
```

Programmatically is 100% right, but logically the result above is WRONG 45.556 should be 45.56 because the last digit we want to get rid of is bigger than 5 out of 10 which is 6 so we have to add 1 to the previous number which is 5 to be 6 to have the result: 45.56. It's math not me.
The other way will give us the right result with digit length needed:

```
Dim a As Double 'This must be DOUBLE not long
a = 45.556

MsgBox Format(a, "#.##") 'Result: 45.56
```

Before "." it's enough to use one #, but after "." we add # as the number of digits we need to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
fix(45.556*100)/100
```

45.55